# How to load assembly into different application domain?

Tags: c#, .net

I believe the default behavior when loading assembly is into the same application domain as the caller. How can I load the assembly into another application domain?

Comment: See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/clr/thread/7127b294-d87e-4aac-a001-bf36a7dd3e5f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `AppDomain::Load` method to load an assembly into a particular `AppDomain` instance